# Selecting unique column values and returning corresponding values in mysql table

Tags: mysql

| SlNo | UserID | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | Three |
| 2 | 002 | Three |
| 3 | 001 | Three |

I have the following table named 'userdata' and I would like to get the points of just the unique usernames.

```
SELECT points from userdata where USERID==distinct
```

Is there a functionality in mysql that works similar to ==     ?

Comment: Expected output??

Answer (score 1):

Use `Distinct`

**Query**

```
Select distinct UserId, points
From userdata;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities

`IN` clause or a `INNER JOIN`

Latter will be faster on big tables

> ```
> CREATE TABLE userdata (
>   `SlNo` INTEGER,
>   `UserID` INTEGER,
>   `points` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO userdata
>   (`SlNo`, `UserID`, `points`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '001', 'Three'),
>   ('2', '002', 'Three'),
>   ('3', '001', 'Thr');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `points` FROM userdata WHERE `UserID` IN (SELECT `UserID` FROM userdata GROUP BY `UserID` HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> | points |
> | :----- |
> | Three  |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `points` 
> FROM userdata  u1 INNER JOIN (SELECT `UserID` FROM userdata GROUP BY `UserID` HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) u2  ON u1.`UserID` = u2.`UserID`
> ```
>
> ```
> | points |
> | :----- |
> | Three  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9324db680c223edcda14317556247321)*